# PowerShell ProccesorAffinity CPU Designation

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set a script that, when a service is restarted, the script resets the processor affinity to the settings I want.

The code I have used for other projects has worked in the past, but is now failing.

```
$Process = Get-Process -Name 'SpaceEngineersDedicated'
$Process.ProcessorAffinity = 254

$Process = Get-Process -Name 'SpaceEngineersDedicated'
$Process.ProcessorAffinity = 255
```

If I had to guess, this is because this is the first time I have tried to set up such a script on a server with two CPUs. (254,255 was for a computer with only one CPU) The server has 16 cores/threads total.

The goal of this script is to force the service to use all cores, as it only uses one core/thread (Core 0, Node 0) originally. I can do this manually from Task Manager, so I am not sure why it fails.

The error the code spits out says that the property ProcessorAffinity cannot be found on this object.

Comment: If I had to guess, your `Get-Process` call is returning an array of processes.

Comment: Run `Get-Process  | Format-Table -Property Name, ProcessorAffinity`

Comment: By setting the affinity manually, you are trying to outsmart the scheduler which is rarely a good idea. Did you test the performance difference? Is it noticeable? How did you test?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, the difference is very noticeable. The service in question is for a multiplayer game.

When the game is handling a lot of physics calculations, the difference is a solid 0.4 difference in "sim speed", which has a max of 1.0.

Comment: @JosefZ Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Yes, there are several services that run under this name. Do I need different syntax to account for this? I want all of them to share the same effect.

Comment: @PatrickR. `@(Get-Process -Name 'SpaceEngineersDedicated').ProcessorAffinity = 255` This will work if you're on v3+

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It is reporting the same error.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation.

Comment: @PatrickR. - Does `@(gps SpaceEngineersDedicated) | % {$_.ProcessorAffinity = 255}` work? If not, post a screenshot of your actual message including the output of `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers That seems to have worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That was actually @TheIncorrigible1 's comment formulated differently. Good it worked.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yeah, I forgot member enumeration doesn't allow a mass-set.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Get-Process` call is returning multiple processes.  In the below syntax, we force these to come back as an array of processes and loop over them to set the property:

```
@(Get-Process -Name 'SpaceEngineersDedicated') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.ProcessorAffinity = 255 }
```

You cannot utilize Member Enumeration to set properties if more than one is returned:

```
## This doesn't work unless .Count = 1
@(Get-Process -Name 'SpaceEngineersDedicated').ProcessorAffinity = 255
```